# how to save or convert holoviews object to image or video

Tags: python, opencv, holoviews

I am trying to detect an image through a detector and want to save it to video or image, but I could not find anything with holoviews DynamicMap to save to image or to video. Please help

```
    fname=r'D:\tiff_data\output_0302.tif'
    #fname=r'D:\cite-on-main\poly_wet (1209).tif'
    save='outputs/demo'
    os.makedirs(save,exist_ok=True)
    
    im=Image.open(fname)
    import cv2
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    
    
    median=np.median(img,axis=2)
    
    upscaling=0.9
    detector=Detector('./weights/', gpu='0', init_shape=img.shape[:2], init_upscaling=upscaling)
    
    def explore(Score, Upscaling):
        width  = median.shape[1]
        height = median.shape[0]
        detections=detector.detect(median,Score,Upscaling)
        aaa = hv.Image((np.arange(width),np.arange(height),median)).opts(title='',invert_yaxis=True, cmap='gray',width=median.shape[1]*scale, height=median.shape[0]*scale,)*hv.Path([hv.Bounds(tuple(r)) for r in detections[:,:4]]).opts(color='lime')
        return aaa
    dmap=hv.DynamicMap(explore, kdims=['Upscaling','Score'])
    dmap.redim.values( Score=np.arange(0.1,1,0.05), Upscaling=np.arange(1,3,0.1))
```

[for reference i have added an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5JEZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a DynamicMap to a HoloMap (http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Live_Data.html#converting-from-dynamicmap-to-holomap) and export a HoloMap to a png or gif or mp4 (https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Exporting_and_Archiving.html). You may need to install some extra dependencies depending on your backend, but the error messages should guide you to what you need. Exporting Matplotlib output is generally easier and faster than Bokeh output, but both should work.